# Testing a ResizeObserver inside an Effect Fn

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm struggling a bit with unit testing the following:

```
    const { element, state } = props;
    const { theme } = state;
    const { computedHeight, computedWidth   } = theme;
    const elementToSize = document.querySelector(element);

    const observer = new ResizeObserver(element => {
        const { contentRect } = element[0];

        // set the viewport size in the state
        dispatch(setViewportSize(state, contentRect.width, contentRect.height));

        // perform the task function
        wrapper(600, computedWidth, computedHeight, contentRect.width, contentRect.height).
            then(() => {
                elementToSize.style.height = `${contentRect.height <= computedHeight ? contentRect.height : computedHeight}px`;
                elementToSize.style.width = `${contentRect.width <= computedWidth ? contentRect.width : computedWidth}px`;
            }).catch( e => new Error(e));
    });

    observer.observe(document.documentElement);

    const wrapper = async (ms, ...callbackArgs) => {
        try {
            await asyncInterval(checkSize, ms, ...callbackArgs);
        } catch {
            new Error('async Interval has failed...');
        }

        return await asyncInterval(checkSize, ms, ...callbackArgs);
    };
};

export const SizeableEffect = (element, state) => [effectFn, { element, state } ];
```

In the code above, I have difficulties with unit testing the code inside the ResizeObserver.
I have the following in my test.

```
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';
import { SizeableEffect } from 'effects';
import { domMock } from '../mocks/dom';

jest.mock('resize-observer-polyfill');

describe('SizeableEffect', () => {
    let stateMock, dispatch, effect, effectFn;

    beforeEach(() => {
        stateMock = {
            viewportWidth: null,
            viewportHeight: null,
            theme: {
                chatFrameSize: {
                    width: 300,
                    height: 500
                }
            }
        };

        dispatch = jest.fn();
        effect = SizeableEffect('elementMock', stateMock);
        effectFn = effect[0];

        Object.defineProperties(window, {
            document: {
                value: domMock()
            }
        });
    });

    it('the effect should be called with the element', () => {
        expect(effect[1]).toEqual(
            expect.objectContaining({
                element: 'elementMock',
                state: stateMock
            })
        );
    });

    it('the effect function should perform the operations', () => {
        effectFn(dispatch, { element: 'some', state: stateMock });
        expect(document.querySelector).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some');
        expect(dispatch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(ResizeObserver).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

And as you can see from the screenshot, I have uncovered lines where the `ResizeObserver` is doing the login by measuring the width' and height's against the viewport. [image: Code uncovered by the unit tests]

How can I cover those lines in the best way?